# Вывести буквы в алфавитном порядке + их количество

Tags: c#

Посчитать в строке количество русских гласных букв. Вывести все  русские гласные буквы строки в алфавитном порядке.

```
        SortedSet<char> s = new SortedSet<char>
        {'а','е','и','о','у','э','ю','я'};
        SortedSet<char> res = new SortedSet<char>();
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s.Contains(str[i]))
                res.Add(str[i]);
        }
        foreach (char с in res){ }
```

Comment: Что сами то успели написать? Если ничего, то бяда… Такие вопросы остаются без ответа и их потом закрывают.

Comment: Писал.. Но ни как не могу сделать.

Comment: Под вопросом есть надпись "Править". Вставьте хотя бы то, что успели написать.

Comment: А почему вы решили использовать `SortedSet` а не лист или массив?

Comment: Мне сказали делать через SortedSet.

Comment: Через SortedSet ни как не сделать?

Comment: Если вы хотите к кому-то обратиться, то в начале комментария нужно написать @<имя пользователя>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Other()
{
    var letters = new SortedSet<char> {'а', 'е', 'и','о','у','э','ю','я'};
    var s = "Хватит копейки считать год от года. Стань депутатом - воруй у народа.";
    var x = letters.ToDictionary(c => c, c => s.Count(z => z == c));
    foreach (var w in x.Keys)
    {
        WriteLine($"Буква '{w}', количество: {x[w]}");
    }
}
/*
Результат:
    Буква 'а', количество: 7
    Буква 'е', количество: 2
    Буква 'и', количество: 3
    Буква 'о', количество: 7
    Буква 'у', количество: 3
    Буква 'э', количество: 0
    Буква 'ю', количество: 0
    Буква 'я', количество: 0
*/
```

P.S. У Вас в примере буква `а` - английская.

Comment: А я скопировал ,думаю, что такое почему "а" не видит, так бы первый ответ выложил...

Comment: @SeeSharp Я тоже сначала не понял, но периодически получая от пользователей файлы Excel с такой проблемой, сразу предположил, что буква `а` - английская. 

Comment: @SeeSharp А какое у Вас решение? 

Comment: @JohnyL гений..

Comment: @Olidger Это было просто 